# `cd` into a directory using a pattern

Tags: regex, linux, cd

I am trying to cd into a directory which is named with an ip address(eg: 10.0.10.10). The name of the folder changes as the ip address of the node changes. I want to have dynamic `cd` command to cd into that folder. `cd ~/mnt/<ip address pattern>`

[image: folder structure]

It works if I use `cd ~/mnt/1*` or any other similar wildcard operator is used. I want it to be worked with the pattern `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`

Comment: What if multiple arguments match your regex? Do you want to `cd` into only the first?

Comment: Why not explicitly get the node's IP address and go there directly, without a pattern?

Comment: BTW, in the future, paste your terminal session *as text*, not a graphical screenshot. Screenshots aren't searchable, and make trouble for folks using text-based browsers, assistive technologies such as screen readers, etc. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122, describing why screenshots are unwelcome here in more detail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If your `find` supports `-regex` (you may want to add `-regextype` with GNU `find` systems or `-E` on BSD `find` to enable ERE syntax):

```sh
re='(^|/)[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'
IFS= read -r -d '' dirname < <(find /mnt -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex "$re" -print0)
[[ $dirname ]] && cd "$dirname"
```

...or you can just use native bash:

```sh
re='(^|/)[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'
for dir in /mnt/*; do
  [[ $dir =~ $re ]] && { cd "$dir" && break; }
done
```